# Strange behavior with flexslider: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

Tags: javascript

When I logged into a dev version of my site flexslider was broken. Rather than a slide show, I have the slideshow images repeating down the page in a single column [image: broken flexslider]. I get a js error in the console that reads `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function` in the jquery.min script.

I'm baffled because I don't recall changing anything, and another dev version of the site doesn't have the issue. The only thing I've done recently is zip the sites folder to move it to a test server which doesn't exhibit the issue.

From googling this is a jquery issue, but I'm at a loss to diagnose how to fix this.

Any help appreciated

EDIT: Not an issue of jquery versioning. Both versions of the dev site (on my local machine) and the live site are all using jquery version 1.5.

EDIT 2: Noticed an issue with my drupal install, specifically flexslider library wasn't there. So, I copied the library to the libraries folder, flushed caches, and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex slider library was missing. Pretty hard to diagnose by itself without the drupal system warning. I looked over the issues more carefully, and there it flagged that the flexslider library was missing. I'd been moving around a lot of files, and I suppose it must not have copied.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Install jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. Seems like your jQuery version is out of date.

Comment: So, it's been a while since I posted this. It's not the jQuery version. I checked it against my live site, and they're running on the same version.